# Getting HTML form data to ASP.NET controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have a view containing a HTML login form and I need to get the values from the form to a controller via post. Right now I'm trying to display the username of the user through the Content method when the form is submitted, once I know I have the username in the controller I can do the rest. The problem I have is that when I submit the form the username is not displayed, I've outputted to the console to check if the controller action is being called and it isn't.

Any help is greatly appreciated cheers!

**View**

```
@{
    @model AdminPanel.Models.cUser
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<head>
    <link href="~/Content/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Div containing the log in box parent -->
    <div class="log-in-box-parent">
        <h2>LOG IN</h2>

        <div class="log-in-form">
            <form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Login">
                <input asp-for="Username" type="text" id="Username" placeholder="Username" /> <br />
                <input aso-for="Password" type="password" id="Password" placeholder="Password" /> <br />
                <input type="submit" id="login" value="Log in"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
using AdminPanel.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AdminPanel.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Login
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(cUser user)
        {
            return Content($"Hello {user.Username}");
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my user model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AdminPanel.Models
{
    public class cUser
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you have a typo in your password element.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo but it still doesn't work

Comment: It wasn't intended to fix *that* issue.

Comment: Please try changing `asp-for="Username"` to `asp-for="user.Username"`

Comment: Thanks again but that didn't fix it, I don't think the Action is being called at all

Comment: "I don't think"...well you can easily prove/disprove that by setting breakpoints in your C# code, and watching your browser's network tab to see what requests get made. Actually though I noticed that your Login action only accepts POST requests, but your `<form` does not have an `method="POST"` attribute

Comment: Then you need to do some debugging.  Open your browser's dev tools and look.

Comment: *I know the action isn't being called, I've attempted to log the username to the output. It wasn't shown and therefore I know the action isn't be called

Comment: Open your browser dev tools and look at the request.  You need to gather diagnostics.  Find out why it isn't being called.

Comment: I usually use `asp-for="@Model.SOMEPROPERTY"`, so for your case it would be `asp-for="@Model.Username"`

Comment: By the way what i said about the anti forgey token was wrong. .net core forms automatically add the token unless you explicitly ask it not to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery

Comment: What happend if you remove the Id=username and Id=password on your inputs? ng-for is supposed to insert that.

Comment: @TheoCrowley **Do not edit your answer directly into the question.** Write an answer.  I have reverted your edit.

Comment: @Harry ng-for is related to AngularJS, which isn't being used here. Wrong framework.

Comment: asp-for :/ @ADyson

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your Login action only accepts POST requests, but your `<form` tag does not have a `method="post"` attribute which would tell the form to perform a POST request (instead of a GET). I think you need to set that in order for it to make the correct request to the action method.

```
<form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Login" method="post">
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms contains an example of this as well.

Comment: @TheoCrowley "It doesn't work" doesn't tell ADyson *anything* he can use to make a better answer.  You have a wealth of information available to you in your browsers dev tools.  *Use it.*

Comment: The problem is exactly the same as before? You should have checked as I have solved it myself using a different method

Comment: "You should have checked as I have solved it myself using a different method"  That has nothing to do with my point.  You need to give better feedback precisely because we cannot do it for you.  What response code are you getting?  What are your headers?  What is the JSON payload?  What is the error message in response?  Is there an error message?  Is it hitting the method?  Is it sending the wrong Content-Type?  We don't know the answers to any of these questions.

Comment: @TheoCrowley it doesn't matter if the issue is "unchanged".  We cannot see your screen, nor can we gather diagnostics.  A change might produce a different outcome, but still not give the expected result.  We don't know.  As a result we're shooting in the dark.  Only you can provide us with the information we need.

Comment: I wont bother making posts like this in the future if im expected to know what all that means to ask a bloody question about HTML forms hahaha.

Comment: The point is you need to provide useful feedback if you expect to be helped.  This is true everywhere in life.

Comment: @TheoCrowley "if im expected to know what all that means...all of those things Amy mentioned are things you need to understand when debugging with HTML, Javascript and HTTP requests. If you don't want to learn them or know about them fine but you won't get very far in web development, if I'm being brutally honest, because you'll keep coming up against relatively simple problems and be powerless to diagnose them yourself. Amy's advice is good and I would take it.

Comment: @TheoCrowley Also if you solved it yourself, where is your answer? What was the problem. You can post an answer here for the benefit of future readers and accept it, then people who have similar issues can gain some insight. That's the whole point of this site.

Comment: I added an edit to the original post however someone appears to have removed it for some reason? I'll add an answer now.

Comment: @TheoCrowley Amy seems to have posted a comment explaining why it was removed. Answers belong in the answers section, which seems obvious when you say it like that. A question makes no sense if it already  appears to contain the answer :-) Also you forgot to "accept" your answer - you can do this to any answer including your own. Then it's clear to future readers which thing worked. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those of you who tried to help me , I solved the problem by using HTML Helpers instead when creating the form. My edited View can be seen below.

```
@model AdminPanel.Models.cUser

@{

    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<head>
    <link href="~/Content/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Div containing the log in box parent -->
    <div class="log-in-box-parent">
        <h2>LOG IN</h2>

        <div class="log-in-form">

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { placeholder = "Username" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { placeholder = "Password" })
                <input type="submit" id="login" value="Log in"/>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting that this worked but tag helpers didn't. `using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post))` should be functionally equivalent to `<form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Login" method="post">`. Are you absolutely certain you're using ASP.NET Core, and not traditional ASP.NET? Tag helpers (i.e the `asp-for` syntax are new in ASP.NET Core and should work they way you showed (with the addition of a method attribute in the case of the form). If you're using the older ASP.NET, then they definitely won't work.

Comment: Your other code makes it look more like older ASP.NET than Core as well. e.g. if it was Core you should need `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;` at the start of your controller class, but you haven't got it, you've got the reference to `System.Web.Mvc;` instead. It looks like you are simply not using the technology you think you are.

Comment: If you're new to web dev you've with .NET you've unfortunately arrived at a confusing moment where MS is in the process of transitioning to a new-style framework (.NET Core). There are a lot of similarities to the older .NET but enough differences too. Annoyingly they decided to give these two things sufficiently similar names for it to be potentially confusing, especially to those not familiar with the history. You'll have to pay close attention to exactly which technology you're using, and therefore which documentation etc you need to refer to.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure I'm not using .NET Core. I'm out at the moment and can't check. Should I be using .NET Core instead or should I just stick with .NET? Cheers

Comment: It's up to you. Core is probably the thing to go for in the longer term but it's not fully mature yet, and regular .NET is not going anywhere for the foreseeable future. .NET Core is also cross-platform, which might help you if you want to develop or deploy your code on Linux or Mac. However, the answer I gave, for instance, was based on you having tagged the question with .NET Core and also using .NET Core syntax yourself, which I presume you'd got from a tutorial without realising it wasn't the same thing?

Comment: Yeah I followed two different tutorials one was how to set up a blank MVC project and the second was how to deal with HTML forms. I wasn't aware of this ASP.NET vs ASP.NET Core thing. Thanks again, I'm going to switch to Core so I'm using the latest thing.

Comment: These links might help you understand a bit better and make a good decision ("latest" is not always "best", for one thing, and also both frameworks are still fully supported, you're not working on a legacy platform if you choose .NET). There are good reasons for choosing either: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-or-asp-net-core-what-to-choose/